# How to access a string from a pointer returned by a function in C

Tags: c, string, function, pointers

I've a function returning a pointer to a string in C and I'm trying to access the entirety of the string but I'm not sure how to.

I've a function that loops threw a linked list of structs containing student data and gets the student's names. I want to pad spaces onto the ends of each string so they are all the same size. So I wrote a function for padding the strings. The function returns a pointer to the string but I don't know how to access the whole string from the pointer. I know I can put *pstring to get the first character of the string but I'm a little lost on how to get the rest.

This loops through the linked list:

```
void myFunction(void) {

    pStudent = pHead;
    char paddedName[30];
    long nameLength = 0 ;

    while(pStudent->pNext != NULL){
        printf("%c,\n", *padstring(pStudent->name));
        strcpy(paddedName, padstring(pStudent->name));
        nameLength = strlen(paddedName);
        printf("%lu | %s | %s \n", nameLength, paddedName, pStudent->name);
        pStudent = pStudent->pNext;
    }
    printf("\n");

}
```

This pads and returns the string:

```
char *padstring(char* string){

    char name[30];
    int i = 0;

    while(i < 30){
        if(i < strlen(string)){
            name[i] = string[i];
                    }
        else{
            name[i] = ' ';
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s,\n", name);
    return name;

}
```

Comment: You can't return name like you are doing.  It is a local variable which is created on the stack and "disappears" when the function exits.

Comment: Trying to return a local character array from within a function is a common mistake.  Many of the basic types (char, int, float, double, etc) and even structs can be returned because the compiler returns a copy.   A local character array variable is a pointer to an "array" (consecutive) characters on the stack.  The value of the pointer is returned correctly, but the stack is rolled back when the function exits so the array of characters that the result points to is no longer valid.  The same goes for local arrays of any type.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary to create a new string. You can output a string right-padded to a certain length using the format specifier below (e.g.: `%-30s` to right-pad to 30 characters):

```
printf("[%-10s]", name);

/* [Name      ] */
```

If you do create a new string, you'd want to return a valid memory location. Rather than returning a pointer to the local stack, use `malloc` to allocate the memory and remember to `free` it when done with it (alternatively pass in an array allocated on the stack by the caller).

Comment: I was just going to suggest that last part. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to dynamically allocate `name` in `padstring()` if you wish to return that memory to the caller.

```
char *name = malloc(30);
if (name == NULL) {
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to null terminate your strings. Second, you need to create the array on the heap using malloc (make sure to free the memory when you are done with it).

Answer (score 0):

I generally prefer to do the padding in the same string.  Of course you have to make sure there is enough space which you can do by passing the maximum size.  I pass the pad length to make it more flexible.  It can be further improved by passing the character that you want to pad with in case it isn't always a space.

This is a quick example.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* padstring(char *s, int maxlen, int padlen)
{
    int len = strlen(s);

    if (len < padlen)
    {
        char *p = s + len;
        while ((len < maxlen) && (len < padlen))
        {
            *p++ = ' '; // Add a space
            *p = 0;     // Null terminate
            len++;
        }
    }

    return s;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char s[50] = "Hello";

    printf("'%s'\n", padstring(s, sizeof(s), 30));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to define a new function in your case.
Just use `sprintf()` to fill string with spaces.

```
void myFunction(void) {

    // Declare max length of name
    const int MAX_LEN = 29;

    pStudent = pHead;
    char paddedName[MAX_LEN + 1];
    long nameLength = 0 ;

    while(pStudent->pNext != NULL){
        // Record origin length
        nameLength = strlen(pStudent->name);
        // Just write spaces after pStudent->name
        sprintf(pStudent->name + nameLength, "%-*s", MAX_LEN - nameLength, "");

        nameLength = strlen(pStudent->name);
        printf("%lu | %s | %s \n", nameLength, paddedName, pStudent->name);
        pStudent = pStudent->pNext;
    }
    printf("\n");

}
```